# Python -- appending to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

For some reason when I try to append elements on to my dictionary, instead of adding on to the dictionary it just overwrites the data and only stores the latest key and item.  Sorry if this is a beginner mistake -- still learning dictionaries

```
def filetodict(vcfFile):
    dictionary = {}

    with open(vcfFile , 'rb') as file:


        for row in csv.reader(file , delimiter = '\t'):
            if "#" in row[0]:
                continue
            dictionary.update( {row[0]:row[1:]} )
    return dictionary
```

Comment: Please note that dictionary keys are unique. So if you add to your dictionary with a key that already exists you will overwrite it to hold the newer value you are adding.

Comment: you could do what you are describing by having the `dictionary value`s as `list`s to which you can `append` stuff as you read through your file.

Comment: use `dictionary = defaultdict(list)` and keep appending to it.

Comment: or you could use `pandas` which is an excellent module and highly suited to this sort of thing.

Comment: Hey, could you provide some feedback about the information you are handling? There are different solutions to your problem depending on the information and the way you want to serialize it.

Answer (score 2):

it's a beginner mistake, but it's common. I think you are mixing concepts here.

Dictionaries hold information using `key:value` pairs, where the `keys` are unique per dictionary and they are used to index information.

Lists, on the other hand are sequences indexed by a range of numbers. Like this `foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, and they are accessed using their index number, e.g: `foo[0]` returns `'a'`.

So, regarding your question, I think you are trying to generate what is commonly known as a `collection` which is a list of dictionaries.
E.g:

```
a = [
    {'name': 'juan'},
    {'name': 'pedro'},
]
```

So, regarding your questions, what I'd do is something like this:

```
def file_to_collection(vcfFile):
    collection = []  # This will hold every dict per row

    with open(vcfFile , 'rb') as file:
        for row in csv.reader(file , delimiter = '\t'):
            if "#" in row[0]:
                continue  # this ignores the first line, it's okay
            collection.append({row[0]: row[1:]})
    return collection
```

Hope to have helped, tell me if this is what you were looking for.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What you can use is `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def filetodict(vcfFile):
     d = defaultdict(list)

     with open(vcfFile , 'rb') as file:


         for row in csv.reader(file , delimiter = '\t'):
             if "#" in row[0]:
                 continue
             d[row[0]].extend(row[1:])
     return dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Don´t use update to append, just do it this way:

```
def filetodict(vcfFile):
    dictionary = {}    
    with open(vcfFile , 'rb') as file:
        for row in csv.reader(file , delimiter = '\t'):
            if "#" in row[0]:
                continue
            dictionary[row[0]]=row[1:]
    return dictionary
```

Comment: I tried running this and it would overwrite the key and item like my original problem

Answer (score 0):

indentation error, corrected as following

```
    if "#" in row[0]: 
        dictionary.update( {row[0]:row[1:]} )
```

besides, you can try `dictionary[row[0]] = row[1:]` as well

Comment: no i dont want any rows containing '#' in my dictionary